# How to squeeze a time domain signal (to increase its frequency) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, time, frequency

I have a 1D signal of length 1x48 as follows:

```
h = [-0.00265429202364732   0.00114381559623147 0.00908984174155875 0.0183092424104111  0.0211504546133937  0.00770487019300306 -0.0267214048940936 -0.0720838840492711 -0.0997128821116885 -0.0725675276244839 0.0291024753407948  0.179241574214812   0.298171242995671   0.284570146378536   0.0817474628244779  -0.259613052052673  -0.574126734090367  -0.656991438427717  -0.392367536944054  0.145508194624853   0.699248579096810   0.960789439152323   0.757486942825664   0.170755448210657   -0.498796897953831  -0.904761150789826  -0.856496441492131  -0.419554007897496  0.143113035135791   0.539681841427904   0.612572904069275   0.398909459502485   0.0701631492551362  -0.189524355981899  -0.282109382620421  -0.220926595018094  -0.0887181885881753 0.0277116422165095  0.0824062595946282  0.0772777428539982  0.0415608034306098  0.00566535573566328 -0.0142417524165823 -0.0174044104259903 -0.0112752491506654 -0.00370981479490947    0.00105712046376533 0.00248943884050455];
```

I need to somehow squeeze this signal to increase its frequency. 
Thanks to "rayryeng", please see the following plot. The green one (squeezed one) is obviously a kind of downsampled version of the blue one. Let's say we have the blue signal saved as an image. Open that image in paint or photoshop etc. Now grab the side and squeeze it by mouse (horizontally). You can see that the nature and shape of the squeezed one is as like as the original one. I want to have that kind of squeezed signal. Here in the picture below, amplitude is changed. It shouldn't. If you squeeze the blue one in paint or photoshop the amplitude never changes.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to reduce the amount of points to represent the signal? I don't understand what exactly you're asking.

Comment: No. Did you plot the given data? If you do so, you will see the signal contains an oscillating pulse (output of an ultrasound sensor). Now assume that we want to keep the signal's length as it is (length=48), and squeeze that oscillating part... In other words, if the oscillating part for the given h1 is now h1(1,5:42), we want to have a new h1_new such that h1_new(1, 15:30) contains oscillating part and the rest is zero. Note that, in order to do so, you need to first squeeze h1 by a factor and then make the h1_new

Comment: No, I didn't plot it because I shouldn't have to.  You should include everything about the question so that we can answer it properly.  We aren't mind readers.  Also, your statement about `h1` and `h1_new` doesn't make much sense to me.  The indices don't agree with your statement.  Please update your question so that we have all of the facts.

Comment: clear enough for you now?!

Comment: OK.  I think I have an idea of what you want.  Try my answer below.  However, it'll be up to you to figure out where you want to position the final squeezed signal.

Comment: they are correct... the given one is h1... the one that we want to obtain is h1_new

Comment: If you want to shift a signal in frequency, modulate it with a complex exponential. Something like: `x_freqshifted = x .* exp(1j*2*pi*f_shift*timevec)`.

Comment: To squeeze a signal, use Matlab's function `squeeze`:-P On a more serious tone: see my answer

Comment: Your data fundamentally has no frequency associated with it, because it has no time variable. How are you plotting it? If you are just doing `plot(h)`, you can "squeeze" it by doing `plot((1:length(h)/2,h)` to double the "frequency".

Answer (score 2):

If you squeeze the signal maintaining the sample period you *lose accuracy*. That's why the amplitude changes. The squeezing works by *averaging neighbouring samples*. Consider for example the original peak sample. Since it is averaged with some lower-value samples, the squeezed signal has *smaller peaks*.

It would be better to do the opposite, i.e "enlarge" the signal horizontally by a factor `r`, and consider that your new sample period is `r` times smaller (finer) than before. So the original signal is now sampled more finely, and the squeezed signal has the same accuracy as the original one.

For that you can use [`resample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html):

```
h2 = resample(h,5,2); %// resample factor in this example: 5/2
plot(h, 'b');
hold on
plot(h2, 'r');
```

[image]

Comment: Nice.  I was about to suggest that, but you beat me to it :)  Thanks for answering this question which clearly lacked effort.  I had to ask the OP on several occasions to clarify his / her problem statement.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your answer. One question and one comment:    Question) Then why that is not a problem in photo editor software such as photoshop? or even when you drag and squeeze an image in Windows?  Comment) In my application I do need to squeeze (not expanding as you mentioned above)... what should I do?

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry about that :-) Yes, the question was not very clear

Comment: @LuisMendo - No problem :) Well, I did do that to you earlier today with the random string integer assignment problem!  Good work btw!

Comment: Ok, let me update you: One of my friends says he can write a code to read data from squeezed image in any photo editor software. That is, the image is squeezed in photo editor first, then saved, then the code reads data from that image. He sent me some samples and it works. Let me see if I can post it here.

Comment: @AlbertoCastilloGraza So you want to squeeze a 1D-signal or a (2D-)image?

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to squeeze the given 1D signal. To avoid the sampling problem, one way is to plot the given 1D signal as you did. Now you have an image. Right? Save that image and open it with photoshop. Now use mouse and squeeze it horizontally. It perfectly preserves the nature of the original signal. Now take a snap shot or print-screen. Then save the image. Now open it in Matlab and read the data from that image! Got it? time consuming but works very well. You will not face downsampling problem.

Comment: @rayryeng by the way, I am very clear. The solution provided so far does not have desired accuracy. To reach better accuracy (to avoid downsampling effect) I suggested another solution. If you can get perfect accuracy using 1D go ahead.

Comment: Scaling an image removes just as much data as removing data points from the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret "squeezing" as representing the signal with fewer points, but maintaining the same pitch.

As such, you could use some sort of interpolation to do so.  What you can do is specify values from `1` up to the length of your signal as control points and the values of `h` as the output values.  Next, you can specify a reduced number of points but still maintaining a linearly increasing range from `1` up to `48` but have exactly this many points that span this range.  We can use [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to help us do this.  For the interpolation, we can use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).  Let's choose `'spline'` interpolation to have some smoothing in between each keypoint that is produced in the final result.

In other words, try something like this:

```
num_points_reduced = 20;
h = [-0.00265429202364732   0.00114381559623147 0.00908984174155875 0.0183092424104111  0.0211504546133937  0.00770487019300306 -0.0267214048940936 -0.0720838840492711 -0.0997128821116885 -0.0725675276244839 0.0291024753407948  0.179241574214812   0.298171242995671   0.284570146378536   0.0817474628244779  -0.259613052052673  -0.574126734090367  -0.656991438427717  -0.392367536944054  0.145508194624853   0.699248579096810   0.960789439152323   0.757486942825664   0.170755448210657   -0.498796897953831  -0.904761150789826  -0.856496441492131  -0.419554007897496  0.143113035135791   0.539681841427904   0.612572904069275   0.398909459502485   0.0701631492551362  -0.189524355981899  -0.282109382620421  -0.220926595018094  -0.0887181885881753 0.0277116422165095  0.0824062595946282  0.0772777428539982  0.0415608034306098  0.00566535573566328 -0.0142417524165823 -0.0174044104259903 -0.0112752491506654 -0.00370981479490947    0.00105712046376533 0.00248943884050455];
x = 1:numel(h);
y = linspace(1,numel(h),num_points_reduced);
h_reduced = interp1(x, h, y, 'spline');
```

If we plot the original signal as well as the result, this is what it would look like:

```
plot(1:numel(x), h, 1:num_points_reduced, h_reduced);
grid;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question for you. The green one (squeezed one) is obviously a kind of downsampled version of the blue one. Ok, let me explain what I want in another way. Let's say we have the blue signal saved as an image. Open that image in paint or photoshop etc. Now grab the side and squeeze it by mouse. You can see that the nature and shape of the squeezed one is as like as the original one. I want to have that kind of squeezed signal. Here in the above picture, amplitude is changed. It shouldn't. If you squeeze the blue one in paint or photoshop the amplitude never changes.

Comment: @AlbertoCastilloGraza - Ah... that makes more sense.  Please update your original problem statement.  I have another idea I'll try out.